# Most efficient way to search lines that contains array items

Tags: ruby

I have an array with 100 items. I also have a big file with million lines and for each line I want to find whether each of these 100 items are contained in each line. What is the best and efficient way to search ? Right now, here's my algorithm, which is just

```
open file do each line
     array.each do each item
          if line contains item
              found
     end
end
```

Example of items:

```
array = [ '10.10.10.10', '20.20.20.20', ... ] # contains ip addresses
```

I need to search for them in huge log files...

thanks.

Comment: Since this is a Ruby question, could you post Ruby code instead of pseudo code? Some example data would probably be helpful, too.

Comment: Put your IP addresses into a file and run `grep -F -f ip_addresses log_file`

Comment: We need more information. Does this file hold in RAM ? Is it a repetitive task or one-shot task ?

Answer (score 2):

`String#include?` method is handy, but if you ask about the most (computationally) efficient method, you shoud use [triez](https://github.com/luikore/triez) gem (`gem install triez`), which provides prefix and suffix trees. Example:

```
file = <<~TEXT
  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
TEXT

lines = file.split "\n"

require 'triez' # if necessary, gem install triez

t = Triez.new
lines.each_with_index { |line, line_number|
  t.change_all( :suffix, line ) { line_number }
}
```

You can iterate over all the words in your list and very efficiently find on which lines they occur:

```
words = %w[lorem dolor elit foobar]
words.each do |word|
  t.search_with_prefix word do |suffix, line_number|
    position = lines[line_number].size - suffix.size - word.size
    puts "'#{word} occurs on line #{line_number}, position #{position}"
  end
end
#=> 'lorem occurs on line 0, position 0
#=> 'dolor occurs on line 0, position 12
#=> 'dolor occurs on line 3, position 13
#=> 'elit occurs on line 1, position 23
```

Btw. the first thing the Web search engine does after downloading your webpage is constructing its suffix tree. Another gem of interest for string search is [fast_trie](https://github.com/tyler/trie).

Comment: Yes, but will tries work [well], when term being searched is in the middle of the string (not prefix or suffix)?

Comment: Well, actually `triez` gem implements a suffix tree, and suffix trees, as far as I know, are used to efficiently find substrings in the middle of long DNA sequences. I'll try to put together the sample code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I think the trick is that every substring occurring in the middle of a longer string is a prefix of one of the suffixes of the longer string. So as long as you can construct the suffix tree of the longer string efficiently (which you can using Ukonnen's algorithm), you can use it to see if the word of interest is a prefix of any of its members.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting idea. I didn't think it worked this way

Answer (score 1):

The general problem you are interested to solve is well known under **String Matching Problem**. The problem is defined as following:

> Given two strings T and P over a finit alphabet ∑.
>   The string-matching problem is about finding all valid shifts(indices)    with which a given pattern P occurs in a given text T

So you can reduce your problem to the String-Matching-Problem as following:

1. The input file -> sequence of texts
2. The items in the array -> sequence of patterns

The following table shows some String-Matching algorithms, their preprocessing  and matching runtimes. 
Let n = |T_1| + |T_2| + ... + |T_i| and m = |p_1| + |p_2| + ... + |p_j|

```
| Algorithm          | Preprocessing time | Matching time       |
|:-------------------|-------------------:|:-------------------:|
| Naive              |        0           |     O((n - m + 1)m) |     
| Rabin-Karp         |      Theta(m)      |    O((n - m + 1)m)  |   
| Finite Automaton   |       O(m|∑|)      |     Theta(n)        |
| Knuth-Morris-Pratt |      Theta(n)      |      Theta(n)       |
```

For more information you can see the lecture of Erick Domaine about algorithms on string under the following link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NinWEPPrkDQ, or read chapter 32 ,, String Matching" [page 985 - 1013] in the book Introduction to Algorithms known under CLRS.